# Can you use MFA in powershell without using Exchange Online Powershell Module?

Tags: powershell, multi-factor-authentication

I've tried using "Send-MailMessage", but it looks like there isn't a parameter for authentifaction.

Can someone help here?

Answer (score 0):

`Send-MailMessage` has a `Credential` parameter, see an example:

```
$smtpServer = 'smtp.office365.com'
$user = 'smtp@domain.com'
$pass = 'Password'

$creds = [pscredential]::new($user,($pass | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force))

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Credential $creds -To[...]
```

It's should work with MFA Enabled, if not, Generate an App Password and use it instead, See this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/manage-app-passwords-for-two-step-verification-d6dc8c6d-4bf7-4851-ad95-6d07799387e9)